# ANTLR C grammar not recognizing dot notation

Tags: c, antlr, antlr4

We're using ANTLR to parse C, and a lot of our code has the dot notation for structs. It's been awhile since I've written C, but from what I remember, these two statements are synonymous:

```
void hello() {
    this->hello = "hello";
    this.hello = "hello";
}
```

ANTLR is able to parse the `greeting->hello` without any issues, however, the dot notation throws the following error:

```
line 3:4 mismatched input 'this.hello' expecting '}'
```

If we switch the statements like this:

```
void hello() {
    this.hello = "hello";
    this->hello = "hello";
}
```

The errors are:

```
line 2:4 mismatched input 'this.hello' expecting {'__extension__', '__builtin_va_arg', '__builtin_offsetof', '__m128', '__m128d', '__m128i', '__typeof__', '__inline__', '__stdcall', '__declspec', '__asm', '__attribute__', '__asm__', 'auto', 'break', 'case', 'char', 'const', 'continue', 'default', 'do', 'double', 'enum', 'extern', 'float', 'for', 'goto', 'if', 'inline', 'int', 'long', 'register', 'restrict', 'return', 'short', 'signed', 'sizeof', 'static', 'struct', 'switch', 'typedef', 'union', 'unsigned', 'void', 'volatile', 'while', '_Alignas', '_Alignof', '_Atomic', '_Bool', '_Complex', '_Generic', '_Noreturn', '_Static_assert', '_Thread_local', '(', '{', '}', '+', '++', '-', '--', '*', '&', '&&', '!', '~', ';', Identifier, Constant, DigitSequence, StringLiteral}
line 3:8 no viable alternative at input 'this->'
line 4:0 extraneous input '}' expecting <EOF>
```

We're using the [C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4) from the [ANTLR Grammars repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/). That being said, we adjusted it to handle `#include` statements and it can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/slehan/ef50e4aa5f5c1c3af972baeea619a40d). What we've added are these two parsers and these two lexers:

```
includeExpression
    : IncludeDirective includedLibExpression '"'
    | IncludeDirective includedLibExpression '>'
    ;

includedLibExpression
    : IncludedHeaderDirective
    ;

IncludeDirective
    : '#' Whitespace? 'include' Whitespace '"'
    | '#' Whitespace? 'include' Whitespace '<'
    ;

IncludedHeaderDirective
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '.' | '_' | '/')+
    ;
```

Then to use the new parsers, we added the below to `translationUnit`. To make things more confusing, if the line with `includeExpression` in `translationUnit` is commented out, we still get the errors.

```
translationUnit
    :   externalDeclaration
    |   translationUnit externalDeclaration
    |   includeExpression+?
    ;
```

The specific parser that should be picking this up is this:

```
postfixExpression
    :   primaryExpression
    |   postfixExpression '[' expression ']'
    |   postfixExpression '(' argumentExpressionList? ')'
    |   postfixExpression '.' Identifier
    |   postfixExpression '->' Identifier
    |   postfixExpression '++'
    |   postfixExpression '--'
    |   '(' typeName ')' '{' initializerList '}'
    |   '(' typeName ')' '{' initializerList ',' '}'
    |   '__extension__' '(' typeName ')' '{' initializerList '}'
    |   '__extension__' '(' typeName ')' '{' initializerList ',' '}'
;
```

What really puzzles me, is the fact that the dot notation and the arrow notation are one after the other, yet only the arrow notation is recognized.

Comment: "these two statements are synonymous" - they're not, but that depends on the type of `greeting`, so ought not matter for the grammar. You use a dot when greeting is a structure (or in C++ a reference to the structure), and the arrow when greeting is a pointer to the structure.

Comment: Rup is correct (I was about to say the same thing) but that shouldn't be causing a _parse_ error.  I note that your error message does not appear to match your code: `this.hello` instead of `greeting.hello`.  Are you sure you got that output from the input you showed?

Comment: Ahh today I learned. It's very similar code I just wrote one in the file on my machine, and wrote it a little differently here. I'll update the OP.

Comment: Did you change anything about the grammar or are you using the linked grammar as-is? What type of token is `this.hello` recognized as?

Comment: Where in the grammar is the semicolon handled? I can't see a rule for that

Comment: indeed, can you confirm that if you reverse the statements that the error happens with `.` still

Comment: You guys are definitely onto something... I forgot we adjusted to grammar to handle include statements for our use case. I've added that grammar we changed to a gist. With regards to reversing the statements, I will update the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've added the following lexer rule to the grammar:

```
IncludedHeaderDirective
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '.' | '_' | '/')+
    ;
```

This pattern matches the string `this.hello`. So when the lexer reaches line 2 of your input, it could either apply the `Identifier` rule to match `this` or the `IncludeHeaderDirective` rule to match `this.hello`. Since the latter is the longer match, it is chosen as per the maximal munch rule.

Since an `IncludedHeaderDirective` is not a valid expression, you get the error you do. In order to match the `postfixExpression '.' Identifier` rule, `this.hello` would have had to be tokenized as `Identifier, '.', Identifier`, but the existence of the `IncludedHeaderDirective` rule prevents that.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. What would be the best way to adjust this lexer so that it still finds the `.` in an `#include` statement, but doesn't touch dot notation?

Comment: @skylerl The preprocessor should really be its own phase. You can solve your current issue using lexical modes, but that still won't lead you to a standard-compliant implementation of the preprocessor. Note for example that something like `int x = \n#include "file-that-only-contains-the-number-42"\n;` (where the `\n`s are supposed to represent actual newlines) is valid C. In other words: C files don't need to be syntactically valid until after preprocessing and you can't really implement that in one grammar like that.

Comment: If I remember correctly, and like I said my C is very hazy nowadays, but the preprocessor effectively combines the linked header file, and the C file you're writing, right? The use case we have is to just find the links between FileA.c and FileB.h if FileA.c has `#include "FileB.h"`. So what you're saying is, we should have a grammar for the pre-processor, and one for the proper C?

Comment: @skylerl: It depends in part on the complexity (atrociousness) of the code base you're analyzing.  A full-blown C compiler will need to recognize all the abuse that an obstreperous programmer can throw at it.  Your code may be OK being more lax.  (I've been working on a homebrew C parser this morning — someone in my project created it years ago for C90; it needs to be updated a bit for C99, C11, C18!  It's a pain!) .The syntax of unpreprocessed C doesn't necessarily bear much relation to the preprocessed C.  `#define IF if (` — `#define THEN ) {` — `#define ELSE } else {` — `#define ENDIF }` .

Comment: @skylerl The preprocessor effectively copy-and-pasted the contents of the included file at the position of the `#include` directive, yes. The real syntactic analysis is then done after this copy-and-pasting (and the preprocessor's other jobs, such as expanding macros) has taken place. So yes, a proper implementation of this process would need one grammar for the preprocessor and another one for the preprocessed code. The preprocessor could then produce a token stream that the real C parser could process (or it could just write the preprocessed C into a file, which is then parsed by the real...

Comment: ... C parser). Whether you really need all that, depends on what exactly you're doing and, as Jonathan Leffer already pointed out, on whether your
tool needs to be handle all possible C files. If all you want to do is to find out which file includes which other files, you don't even need to pa
rse the C-part at all - only the preprocessor directive. So all you'd need is the grammar for the preprocessor.